# Need to remove Akka Framework from project due to licensing changes

Tags: java, scala, akka, scalaz, zio

I have recently joined a new company and have been assigned to a project that consists of technologies such as Scala, SNMP, Akka Framework, Kafka, Kubernetes, and Spark. However, Lightbend recently announced a change in licensing for Akka Framework, from the open-source Apache 2.0 to the source-available Business Source License (BSL) 1.1. Due to this change, I am tasked with assessing the difficulty involved in removing Akka Framework from the project and finding suitable alternatives.
Can anyone provide insightful information on how to undertake such a task? What are the best alternatives available to Akka Framework, and how do they compare in terms of features, performance, and scalability? Additionally, I would like to know how to evaluate the difficulties involved when removing a framework of this nature from a large project.
I am relatively new to these technologies and transitioning from a background in Java, Spring, and REST APIs, so any detailed insights would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pekko](https://pekko.apache.org/) is a fully-compatible re-build of the latest Open Source version of Akka from the Apache Foundation. Porting to Pekko requires changes to libraries and imports, but few (if any) code changes.

The caveat is that libraries that use Akka may not have Pekko equivalents available. There is a growing number of libraries that have been ported, but it some cases it may be necessary to download open source Akka libraries and manually port them to Pekko.

Comment: Hi @Tim, Thank you for your reply. I appreciate your suggestion about Pekko as an alternative to Akka. However, as the project I will be working on involves technologies such as Scala, Kafka, and Spark, I am a little hesitant about using Pekko, which is a Kotlin-based framework. Also, upon reviewing the Pekko documentation, I noticed that it lacks good examples for developers to get started.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that Pekko is Kotlin? It is a Java/Scala project which, as I said, is a drop-in replacement for Akka. And you don't need examples because you can just use the Akka documentation. All the types and objects have the same names, only the imports need to change.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion @Tim. I also appreciate your insights regarding that I can use the existing Akka documentation and simply change my imports. I will look into Pekko further, and if I have additional questions, I hope it would be okay to reach out to you for guidance. Thank you again for your help. I am accepting your answer.